# Need to generate superset in java

Tags: java, set

Trying to figure out a way to generate a superset using java
need simple answer to

what am looking for is

Input : `ab`

Output : `{} {a} {b} {ab}`

how do i go about this any clue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you. Show what you've done so far and ask a concrete question, or this'll be closed.

Comment: show the codes what you have done,dont expect your answers without any effort

Comment: I think what you mean is the powerset, not the superset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int allMasks = (1 << N);
for (int i = 1; i < allMasks; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)           //The j-th element is used
        System.out.print((j + 1) + " ");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: isn't your answer limited to how many bits are in an integer in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is currently the second result in google for `java superset` I'm going to answer that query.

[Set.addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) will do this.

example:

```
// A couple of sets
Set<Integer> set1 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
Set<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3));

// Generate the superset    
Set<Integer> superset = new TreeSet<>();
superset.addAll(set1); // {1, 2}
superset.addAll(set2); // {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: This is the superset, but I think the one who asked the question wanted the powerset