# Method for finding Mathematical group of groups in Java

Tags: java

For example if the function get this array of strings {A,B,C}
it will return array  of those items:

{"","A","B","C","AB","AC","BC","ABC"}

Comment: did you try anything so far ? please show some effort or some code

Comment: And some helpful implementation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906214/permutation-algorithm-for-array-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620006/need-to-generate-superset-in-java

Comment: This is a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), not a "group of groups".

Comment: Thanks Mike Kobit, yes that what i was looking for, I didnt know how to search for it...